# Find missing/broken native DLL

Tags: c#, python, py2exe

I am programming an application in Python which has to use some DLLs originally created from C# code. Generally the usage of such DLLs is working (proven with multiple DLLs, all from the same source). For deployment on other people computers I'm using Py2Exe which also works as intended.

But now I want to use another DLL and have the following problems. If I start the programm and make a call to a function within the DLL, it throws an error saying:

`.Net Dll broken because of possibly missing native Dlls.`

Now comes the strange part. If I compile the python program into an executable the message does not show up and everything works as intended.

I already tried to identify missing DLLs by comparing the DLL assembly with the ProcessExplorer but they look totally the same. Next thing was to try to set path variables to all Dlls which I am calling directly but this was no solution too.

Other informations which could be interesting are IDE and OS: I'm using Eclipse Indigo with PyDev 2.5 plugin on a Windows 7 machine.

So are there any things I could have overseen or settings which I could try to make it work?
Any suggestions are appreciated.